# Suggestions to improve SQLite perfromance

Tags: android

I am saving data to an SQLite Database. It's taking a while for small amounts of data to be saved. I'm using: beginTransaction();
setTransactionSuccessful();, endTransaction(); etc but it doesn't improve performance. I'm considering switching to RealmDB if I can't improve this. Does anyone have any tips?  Cheers

```
public enum DbSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    public Context context;


    private DatabaseHandler getDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        if (db != null) {
            return db;
        } else {
            if (MainActivity.mainActivity == null) {

                SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);

                return db = new DatabaseHandler(context); //make static context field in area this is used. e.g. main
            } else {
                return db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.mainActivity);
            }
        }
    }


    //will provide one sample for reference now

    public void insert(Context context, String table, ContentValues values) {
           SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(MainActivity.mainActivity);
        //note this line
        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler(context).getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);
        try {
            sql.beginTransaction();


            sql.insert(table, null, values);
            // Log.i("Values being sent to db", values.toString());

            sql.setTransactionSuccessful();
            sql.endTransaction();
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.e("SQL EXCEPTION", ex.toString());
        } finally {
            sql.close();
        }
    }
    public Cursor select(Context context, String statement, String[] selectArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler(context).getReadableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);
        if (selectArgs == null) {

            return sql.rawQuery(statement, null);

        } else {
            return sql.rawQuery(statement, selectArgs);
        }

    }

    public int Update(Context context, String table, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {

        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler(context).getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);
        int count = -1;

        try {
            sql.beginTransaction();
            count = sql.update(table, values, where, whereArgs);
            sql.setTransactionSuccessful();
            sql.endTransaction();
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.e("SQL EXCEPTION", ex.toString());
        }

        if (count == 0) count = -1;
        return count;

    }
    public void Drop(Context context, String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler(context).getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);

        sql.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);

    }
    public void Create(Context context, String table) {

        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler(context).getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);
        sql.beginTransaction();
        sql.execSQL(table);
        sql.setTransactionSuccessful();
        sql.endTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: Try indexing all your search fields. And the Join fields. It improved my performances about 350 to 400 times.

Comment: For updating and selecting I agree with @KlingKlang, for insertions the indexes do not influence that much.

Comment: @BasvanStein Well, for insertions you wouldn't care for the UI refreshing performance anyway. Unless you don't requery the table to update the UI. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your inserts in `beginTransaction()` and `endTransaction()` is only saving time when you do multiple inserts.

So always save your data to one table at once using the following format, this greatly improves performance:

```
ArrayList<String> itemsToInsert; //an array of strings you want to insert
db.beginTransaction();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
for (int i = 0; i < itemsToInsert.size(); i++) {
    values.put('field', itemsToInsert.get(i));
    db.insert(table, null, values);
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

In addition, for selecting from a table, `query()` is performing slightly better than `rawQuery()`, but the difference is small.

---

Als check this article for more background information about SqlLite Performance:
[sqlite-insertions](https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2)

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a new library as part of the architecture components called `Room`.

official doc says:

> The Room persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite
>   to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full
>   power of SQLite.

[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

[Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

More:

You can use the room with another awesome library `(Paging Library)` to handle paging and huge data sets

[Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)